# When does the adjacency matrix of a graph have an eigenvalue zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

When does the adjacency matrix $A$ of an undirected graph $G$ not have full rank? Is there any intuition to understanding this?

Recall that the adjacency matrix of a graph (without parallel edges) is obtained by labeling the vertices and forming the $0-1$ matrix where  $a_{i,j}=1$ if and only if thee is an edge from the $i$-th to the $j$-th vertex.

Comment: It can be a little tricky. There was a question here a few days ago about cycle graphs --- just $n$ vertices in a single cycle, $n\ge3$. Turns out in this case that the adjacency matrix has full rank if and only if $n$ is not a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the paper by Irene Sciriha, *A characterization of singular graphs,* Electronic Journal of Linear Algebra, Volume 16, pp. 451-462, December 2007.

Its abstract reads:

> Characterization of singular graphs can be reduced to the non-trivial solutions of a system of linear homogeneous equations $Ax=0$ for the $0-1$ adjacency matrix $A$. A graph $G$ is singular of nullity $\eta(G)\ge 1$, if the dimension of the nullspace $\operatorname{ker}(A)$ of its adjacency matrix $A$ is $\eta(G)$. Necessary and sufficient conditions are determined for a graph to be singular in terms of admissible induced subgraphs.

I've had a look at the paper, and can't see any simple way to summarize what's in it.

But this paper is [freely available online](https://www.emis.de/journals/ELA/ela-articles/articles/vol16_pp451-462.pdf). If the link stops working go to https://repository.uwyo.edu/ela/, or any resource that has the journal, and navigate to the volume specified above.

Comment: Would it be possible that you expand this post a bit?

Comment: @quid, I've had a look at the paper, and can't see any simple way to summarize what's in it. But maybe this is a better link: https://www.emis.de/journals/ELA/ela-articles/articles/vol16_pp451-462.pdf or go to https://repository.uwyo.edu/ela/ and navigate to the desired volume.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I copied the abstract and included the new links in the post. I hope this edit is fine with you. If not, of course, feel free to modify or rollback. (To explain the context of my activity: we sometimes get flags on such answer, so I tried to do something. I agree that sometimes, as in this case, a direct pointer to the literature is a/the reasonable answer, and I so tried to embellish it a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, if an undirected graph $G$ has an isolated vertex $v$, i.e. a vertex with no neighbors, then the adjacency matrix $A$ has a zero column (and zero row, since the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph is symmetric), which implies that the determinant of $A$ is zero, which means $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Certainly if an undirected graph has an isolated vertex, then the adjacency matrix will have a zero eigenvalue, but many graphs with no isolated veticies also have zero eigenvalues.  Here is a simple example?
$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  This matrix has eigenvalues $-\sqrt{2}, -1, 0, 1, \sqrt{2}$

Comment: While the graph above, does not have an isolated vertex, it is indeed a disconnected vertices 1 and 3 (zero based) only connect to each other.  However, it is not the case that all disconnected graphs have a zero eigenvalue.  For example the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&1&0&1\\1&0&0&0&1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0&0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0&0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0&0&1\\1&0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ represents a disconnected graph, but the eigenvalues are -1 (multiplicity 6) and 3 (multiplicity 2)